# Network Printer "Print Data Error" receives data but does not print Ricoh/Lanier LD520C

Tags: networking, drivers, printing

I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure this out. I just tossed WIN8.1 because I could not make any hardware work, but it had similar symptoms.

- First I tried with Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit
- Then I tried Linux Mint Cinnamon 15 64 bit

Both have the same symptoms.
The Printer appears to install just fine, drivers automatically selected, but test page fails to print. I can see the "data in" light flashing on the copier/printer but the display on the printer shows "Print Data Error" and nothing prints.

The printer requires an authorization code to print in COLOR, but NOT in black and white, so I set the settings to black/white. I also tried putting in the color code with color or black/white printing to no avail. The printer does this same thing when another networked PC tries to print in color without the code. Again there is no code needed for black/white.

`ping` works fine, `nmap` shows it is compatible with a host of different formats including

- 21 ftp
- 23 telnet
- 80 http
- 139 netbios
- 514 shell
- 515 printer
- 631 ipp
- 7443 unknown
- 9100 Jetdirect

`/usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp` command shows:

```
network socket://192.168.1.201 "LANIER MP C2050/LD520C" "LANIER MP C2050/LD520C" "MFG:LANIER;CMD:PJL,RCS,PCL,PCLXL,PCL,PCLXL;MDL:MP C2050/LD520C;STS:10001,0;CLS:PRINTER;DES:LANIER MP C2050/LD520C;" ""
```

`LPINFO -V` command shows the network socket address but no descriptor

The printer isn't giving any feedback except "Print Data Error"
Any help would be helpful. Thanks!
-Peter

Edit: I wanted to add that I tried the method which worked for another poster which was selecting the "Jetdirect" option and specifying the ip address and that did not work either. I do not know how to capture the log file to attach here. I am a complete noob in Linux but I can follow directions if adding that would help.

Answer (score 0):

If printing from a MAC to a Ricoh/Lanier copier you will need an adobe postscript card installed on the machine. To check if machine has an adobe poscript, print out a configuration page, look for printer language, you should see adobe poscript 3 if not then you will need to purchase one through your copier vendor.

Comment: have you got a reference for this? Some more information would help I think

Answer (score -1):

I just had this same problem on my printer and it appears to be a driver issue. When I initially setup the printer I selected the PS driver. When attempting to print I received the same error that you received, "Print Data Error". After switching to the PXL Driver I began printing correctly.